# Make wildcard function is truncating/removing inputted filenames

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying to run a Makefile through GNU Make 4.3, built for i686-w64-mingw32. One of the lines in the Makefile is using the wildcard function in the following way to try and get the name of every .c file in the working directory. However, the names of the files are always truncated, or in some cases outright removed. As an example, I make a bunch of files as so:

```
touch Makefile m_test1.c m_test2.c test_1.c test_2.c test_t1.c test_t2.c test1.c test2.c
```

And fill the Makefile with the following:

```
SRC_C = $(wildcard *.c)

print1:
    $(info $$SRC_C is [${SRC_C}])
```

Yet, the following is printed to the console:

```
$SRC_C is [1.c 2.c t1.c t1.c t2.c t2.c]
```

Comment: The output you show cannot be exactly what you got: there is absolutely no way that `$(info $$SRC_C...)` outputs `#SRC_C...`. Please copy-paste exactly, every detail matters. And check your filenames. As you are apparently in a Windows environment I would not be surprised that they contain all kinds of characters, including non-printable ones.

Comment: Cannot reproduce this here (GNU Make 4.3). My guess is that the filenames you show are not the filenames you have.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I wish that this was the case. These test files aren't even the ones I discovered this with, it just happened to happen to these too; I just made these files to see if the problem was reproducible. I'm also doing nothing before this in this test Makefile, what you see and the result you see is exactly what I'm getting, which is why I'm so confused.

The way I discovered this wasn't through printing with `$(info $$SRC_C is [${SRC_C}])` but because the object files the linker tried to link and failed to find were these same filenames.

Comment: But how do you explain this `#` instead of the expected `$`, for instance?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Ah, apologies, I mistyped that when I was making the post. It's supposed to be a $. (I just checked and verified it now)

Comment: @Elliot I used your Makefile and ran into the same issue. I've asked other people I know to run the same Makefile and they all get the correct result, so I think I'll just try to reinstall make again to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Seems that reinstalling it fixed it. No idea what was causing that to happen, but it's gone now. Thanks for the help! @Elliott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling Make seemed to fix it. I was previously messing with an older version of MinGW in retrospect, so maybe that version of Make just doesn't work properly in more recent Windows versions.